# selenium - phantom js: unable to perform actions on mouseover

Tags: webdriver, phantomjs, driver

I am trying to perform an action on a button but its never done.
I have done mouseover function over a menu.When we hover the menu it show the new button.I want and tried to click the new button using xpath. The code for this work perfectly with firefox but not with phantom JS as the click action on new button is not getting performed.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use evaluate to perform it:

```
page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js");
var res = page.evaluate(function () {
    $('#some_element').trigger('hover');
    return true;
});
```